# Hiding top status bar but keeping the bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

`fullscreen` hides both the Android navigation and status bars (requiring you swipe from the bottom to show the navigation bar over the app), and `standalone` hides neither, when it comes to the `display` property of the PWA's manifest.

Simply, I want the bottom Android navigation bar to always show but without showing the top status bar. I wonder if I am missing some HTML `meta` or manifest JSON property or some other way to accomplish this?

I will expect most users to install the PWA via the web, not via the Play Store (so no TWA, Android application wrapper, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know this is not possible.

With the web-manifest you have different choices: **default, standalone, fullscreen** (see screenshots below):

[image]

On the [Google docs page](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest#display), also a "minimal-ui" value is available:

> This mode is similar to fullscreen, but provides the user with some means to access a minimal set of UI elements for controlling navigation (i.e., back, forward, reload, etc).
>   Note: Only supported by Chrome on mobile.

Reading the description it seems this is what you are looking for, but unfortunately the top status bar and also the page address (read-only) is displayed. Therefore I do not think you can achieve what are you looking for with the standard display values of the web manifest.

Comment: stand alone and full screen produce the same result chrome but when i use firefox with stand alone it gives the desired results `"display": "standalone",`

Comment: standalone and fullscreen both have an address bar for me. It's not one you can type in, it just shows the PWA name with the address under it.... Unlike all of google's examples.